# How to install "sparse_dot_topn" from github python

Tags: python, github, sparse-matrix

I want to install `sparse_dot_topn` in python from github. But I don't know how to do it. I did: `pip3 install sparse_dot_topn` but it failed. I saw `sparse_dot_topn` in github and tried to run the code in jupyter notebook but I couldn't succeed. Maybe I am doing something wrong. Can you please help me with the steps to install `sparse_dot_topn` from github? Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To install from GitHub with pip you can:
pip3 install git+url

example:

```
pip3 install git+https://github.com/ing-bank/sparse_dot_topn.git
```

Comment: I have already tried this, but I am getting an error:
Collecting git+https://github.com/ing-bank/sparse_dot_topn.git
  Cloning https://github.com/ing-bank/sparse_dot_topn.git to /private/var/folders/ml/m_w11qld7jx47_vt403shwpm0000gn/T/pip-req-build-3qtp5v61
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
Command "git clone -q https://github.com/ing-bank/sparse_dot_topn.git /private/var/folders/ml/m_w11qld7jx47_vt403shwpm0000gn/T/pip-req-build-3qtp5v61" failed with error code 1 in None